# Why not use ListIterator for full LinkedList Operation?

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, time-complexity

[image: TimeComplexity For LinkedList]

My main question is if **ListIterator** or **Iterator** class reduces the time taken for removal of the elements from a given LinkedList and the same can be said while adding elements in the same given **LinkedList** using any one of the following classes above. What's the point of using the inbuilt functions of LinkedList class itself? Why should we perform any of the operations through LinkedList functions when we can use the ListIterator functions for better performance?

Comment: Because you do not per se want to (a) create an iterator, (b) iterate to that item; (c) remove it. The `remve` of the iterator works faster in the sense that it ignores an important part: iterating to the correct node.

Comment: Take an example of the add(int index, E element) itself in a LinkedList function. It has to start traversing from the head itself and then go to the correct index and put down the respective object there. The same thing can be done with ListIterator also right ? So what's the basic difference? What are the points where ListIterator should not be used?

Comment: Well, to add an element at index 10, all you need to to is `list.add(10, element)`. Doing that with an iterator would need to create an iterator, call next() 10 times, and finally call add(). It's much less readable, more error-prone, and more verbose. And it isn't faster. Why would you use such an awkward solution instead of just using add()?

Comment: @IcyFlamlex: Because it is more convenient, and tested effectively. By doing the logic yourself with an iterator, you need to write more code, and you might not consider some strange cases (like a negative index, etc.)

Comment: Okay. Understood your explanation clearly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `ListIterator` can indeed efficiently remove the node on which it is positioned. You can thus create a `ListIterator`, use `next()` two times to move the cursor, and then remove the node instantly. But evidently you did a lot of work *before* the actual removal.

Using `ListIterator.remove` is not more efficient "time complexity"-wise than removing through the `LinkedList.remove(int index)` if you need to construct the iterator. The `LinkedList.remove` method takes *O(k)* time, with *k* the index of the item you wish to remove. Removing this element with the `ListIterator` has the same timecomplexity since: (a) we create a `ListIterator` in constant time; (b) we call `.next()` *k* times, each operation in *O(1)*; and (c) we call `.remove()` which is again *O(1)*. But since we call `.next()` *k* times, this is thus an *O(k)* operation as well.

A similar situation happens for `.add(..)` on an arbitrary location (an "insert"), except that we here of course insert a node, not remove one.

Now since the two have the same time complexity, one might wonder why a `LinkedList` has such `remove(int index)` objects in the first place. The main reason is *programmer's convenience*. It is more convenient to call `mylist.remove(5)`, than to create an iterator, use a loop to move five places, and then call remove. Furthermore the methods on a linked list guard against some edge-cases like a negative index, etc. By doing this manually you might end removing the first element, which might not be the intended behaviour. Finally code written is sometimes read multiple times. If a future reader reads `mylist.remove(5)`, they understand that it removes the fifth element, wheres a solution with looping will require some extra brain cycles to understand what that part is doing.

As [@Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57528463/why-not-use-listiterator-for-full-linkedlist-operation/57528584?noredirect=1#comment101523866_57528584) says, furthermore the `List` interface defines these methods, and hence the `LinkedList<T>` should implement these.

Comment: The answer to *"one might wonder why a LinkedList has such remove(int index) objects in the first place"* is that it has to implement the [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface, which [defines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) the method. It wasn't added to *`LinkedList`* because of programmer's convenience, it was added because it had to be. It might have been added to `List` for programmer's convenience, but that's different. The answer to why `LinkedList` has it is not programmer's convenience. Still: +1.